# travis yaml with coverty

Tags: yaml, travis-ci, coverity

I have an YAML file for travis(.travis.yml)

```
language: cpp
compiler:
  - gcc

env:
  global:
   # The next declaration is the encrypted COVERITY_SCAN_TOKEN, created
   #   via the "travis encrypt" command using the project repo's public key
    - secure: "*my secured token for coverity"

addons:
    coverity_scan:
      project:
        name: "*username/project"
        description: "Build submitted via Travis CI"
      notification_email: *my email
      build_command_prepend: "mkdir build && cd build && cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ../project/"
      build_command: "make -j4"
      branch_pattern: master

script: mkdir build && cd build && cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ../project/ && make
```

for some reason this will not parse travis's side...
I have honestly no clue what it is that breaks the yaml...

Comment: [Travis Web Validator](http://lint.travis-ci.org/) yields an error with your TravisCI configuration file.

Comment: exactly, But I cannot find the problem... 
the structure is copied from the coverity website as example, so I thought this should work... I have another project which is almost the same in the config except it is c#

Comment: Have you tried configuration file I posted ?

Comment: I added thebackslashes to  the Unix makefiles that caused it to work again.

Comment: If you put in the backslashes in the above and paste it in the travis file checker (http://lint.travis-ci.org/) you still get a syntax error, you really need to take take care of the `*my email` line, at least by quoting it.

Comment: I think `*my email` is a simple placeholder to not showing it's email. So there is no issue here.

Comment: Oops, forgot to add that yes.
the *email, *username/project  and the *my secured token are placeholders.
My apologies

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with your value for `notification_email`. You use an alias `my` there (indicated by the `*`), but there is no anchor `my` (i.e. `&my` before a mapping, sequence or scalar). Either provide that anchor, or put the whole in quotes if using an alias was not what you intended to do:

```
notification_email: "*my email"
```

On the line below that you use a double quoted string within another one, you should make the outer quotes single quotes:

```
build_command_prepend: 'mkdir build && cd build && cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ../project/'
```

That makes it valid YAML. If you also drop the `description` key that travis doesn't know about:

```
language: cpp
compiler:
  - gcc

env:
  global:
   # The next declaration is the encrypted COVERITY_SCAN_TOKEN, created
   #   via the "travis encrypt" command using the project repo's public key
    - secure: "*my secured token for coverity"

addons:
    coverity_scan:
      project:
        name: "*username/project"
      notification_email: "*my email"

      build_command_prepend: '"mkdir build && cd build && cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ../project/'
      build_command: "make -j4"
      branch_pattern: master

script: mkdir build && cd build && cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ../project/ && make
```

the [Travis WebLint](http://lint.travis-ci.org/) validates the file.

Comment: @LeFlou What did you check that with?

Comment: @LeFlou That is not because it was incorrect YAML, but because Travis doesn't know about the `description` key.

Comment: @LeFlou In order function the YAML first has to be syntactically correct then you can look at the semantics. If you don't you'll never understand why something is not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

It's working better with antislash around Unix Makefiles:

```
build_command_prepend: "mkdir build && cd build && cmake -G \"Unix Makefiles\" ../project/"
```

instead of

```
build_command_prepend: "mkdir build && cd build && cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ../project/"
```

Still there is an issue about description I don't understand why but following configuration file works:

```
language: cpp

compiler:
  - gcc

env:
  global:
   # The next declaration is the encrypted COVERITY_SCAN_TOKEN, created
   #   via the "travis encrypt" command using the project repo's public key
    - secure: "*my secured token for coverity"

addons:
  coverity_scan:
    project:
      name: "Username/Project"
    notification_email: example@example.com
    build_command_prepend: "mkdir build && cd build && cmake -G \"Unix Makefiles\" ../project/"
    build_command: "make -j4"
    branch_pattern: master

script: mkdir build && cd build && cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ../project/ && make
```

Comment: Your missing the `*my` alias that refers to a non-defined anchor (i.e. there is no `&my` in the text).

Comment: It seems the \" did the job for me, I don't have a lot of experience with yaml